# Internet Speed in Pi Zero W

Tags: networking, wireless, pi-zero-w, internet

Internet speed on raspberry pi zero W is too slow. I've measured the speed in same way on my computer with same IP but the result is incredibly different.

Test on raspberry,

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ speedtest-cli 
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from Turk Telekom (88.228.xx.xx)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by Turk Telekom (Burdur) [46.81 km]: 198.977 ms
Testing download speed..............
Download: 0.53 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed.......................
Upload: 1.03 Mbit/s
```

Test on my machine,

```
soner@ubuntu:~$ speedtest-cli 
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Testing from Turk Telekom (88.228.xx.xx)...
Selecting best server based on latency...
Hosted by Turk Telekom (Antalya) [96.81 km]: 51.977 ms
Testing download speed........................................
Download: 9.42 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed..................................................
Upload: 4.29 Mbit/s
```

Here is my DNS,

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nslookup yandex.ru
Server:     208.67.220.220        <----------- OpenDNS
Address:    208.67.220.220#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   yandex.ru
Address: 77.88.55.88
Name:   yandex.ru
Address: 5.255.255.50
Name:   yandex.ru
Address: 77.88.55.50
Name:   yandex.ru
Address: 5.255.255.5
```

How can the issue be fixed?

Comment: Are you using the Pi's Wi-Fi or an ethernet connection? If the former, could distance be a factor, or have you accounted for that?

Comment: @Aurora0001 hummmm, it seems that's right I got 2.74 Mbit/sec, its wifi doodad is of poor quality

Comment: For comparison you should address the same Turk Telekom server (or any other performant server).